# Intercepting Spring Cloud Stream Messages from Consumer only

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I am currently using Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka binders with a `GlobalChannelInterceptor` to perform message-logging for my Spring Boot microservices.

I have:

1. a producer to publish messages to a `SubscribableChannel`
2. a consumer to listen from the Stream (using the `@StreamListener` annotation)

Throughout the process when a message is published to the Stream from the producer and listened by the consumer, it is observed that the `preSend` method was triggered twice:

1. Once at producer side - when the message is published to the Stream
2. Once at consumer side - when the message is listened from the Stream

However, for my logging purposes, I only need to intercept and log the message at consumer side.

Is there any way to intercept the SCS message ONLY at one side (e.g. consumer side)?

I would appreciate any thoughts on this matter. Thank you!

Ref:

1. `GlobalChannelInterceptor` documentation - https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/config/GlobalChannelInterceptor.html

EDIT

**Producer**

```
public void sendToPushStream(PushStreamMessage message) {
        try {
            boolean results = streamChannel.pushStream().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(message)).build());
        log.info("Push stream message {} sent to {}.", results ? "successfully" : "not", StreamChannel.PUSH_STREAM);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            log.error("Unable to parse push stream message.", ex);
        }
    }
```

**Producer's streamChannel**

```
public interface StreamChannel {

    String PUSH_STREAM = "PushStream";

    @Output(StreamChannel.PUSH_STREAM)
    SubscribableChannel pushStream();

}
```

**Consumer**

```
@StreamListener(StreamChannel.PUSH_STREAM)
public void handle(Message<PushStreamMessage> message) {
    log.info("Incoming stream message from {}, {}", streamChannel.pushStream(), message);
```

}

**Consumer's streamChannel**

```
public interface StreamChannel {

    String PUSH_STREAM = "PushStream";

    @Input(StreamChannel.PUSH_STREAM)
    SubscribableChannel pushStream();

}
```

**Interceptor (Common Library)**

```
public class GlobalStreamInterceptor extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> msg, MessageChannel mc) {
       log.info("presend " + msg);
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    public void postSend(Message<?> msg, MessageChannel mc, boolean sent) {
        log.info("postSend " + msg);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right, why don't follow `GlobalChannelInterceptor` options and don't apply

> An array of simple patterns against which channel names will be matched.

?

So, you may have something like this:

```
@GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns = Processor.INPUT)
```

Or use a custom name of input channel to your SCSt app.

Comment: Hi Artem, thanks for the reply. What if the application needs to both publish to and listen from the same channel, would the `patterns` method that you suggested still work?

Comment: That doesn’t make sense for me. Show your application, please. I can’t compile such a logic in my head, sorry

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. Let me word myself better. Please refer to the codes I added above. Applying your suggestion to my case, the annotation becomes `@GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns = StreamChannel.PUSH_STREAM`. However, this does not solve the problem since the interceptor would still intercept the message at both ends of the channel.

Comment: What you show in your code must be in different Microservices, otherwise there is no reason in Kafka in between and channel can be just simple in-memory `MesaageChannel`

Comment: Yes, the producer and consumer are different microservices, thus a Kafka binder is used.

Comment: Great! So, what is the point to have that interceptor in the producer application? Just add it into the consumer and you really can keep the same name for channel!

Comment: thanks for the input. Sorry if i did not make it clear that the `GlobalStreamInterceptor` is a common library. But what if the consumer itself (say B) also acts as a producer to another microservice (say C)? If I do not put the dependency in B, I can't possibly expect to intercept the incoming messages to B. If B still uses the `GlobalStreamInterceptor` dependency, it will intercept outgoing messages to C, which I am trying to avoid here. Thus we are back to square one.